# Read from a file and stdin in Bash

Tags: bash, stdin

I would like to know if I can write a shell script that accepts two arguments **simultaneously**, one from a file and the another one from stdin. Could you give some example please?.

I trying

```
while read line
   do
   echo "$line"
done < "${1}" < "{/dev/stdin}"
```

But this does not work.

Comment: What does "an argument from a file and from stdin" mean? You mean reading the data from a file passed as argument?

Comment: Interleaving the content (one line from the file, one from stdin, switching back and forth)? Concatenating them? Be more specific -- we *probably* have a duplicate, once enough details are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cat -` or `cat /dev/stdin`:

```
while read line; do
  # your code
done < <(cat "$1" -)
```

or

```
while read line; do
  # your code
done < <(cat "$1" /dev/stdin)
```

or, if you want to read from all files passed through command line *as well as stdin*, you could do this:

```
while read line; do
  # your code
done < <(cat "$@" /dev/stdin)
```

---

See also:

- [How to read from a file or stdin in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980090/how-to-read-from-file-or-stdin-in-bash)

Comment: I need that bash script accepts the two arguments simultaneously. I used to second example by doesnot work. I created test.txt and then I make bash myprogram.sh test.txt anything. But I only get the content from the file and not from stdin (anything)

Comment: @Juan what is anything? you want `stdin` literal to be inferred as stdin?

Comment: Updated the answer to take care of all the arguments (file names) passed through command line.

Comment: @Juan, ...also, "does not work" is simply not an adequate error report. Some of the reasons this might not work could relate to execution with the wrong shell (`sh` does not support process substitution syntax), or a typo or syntax error on entry. The comment given above is not sufficient to diagnose any of those cases -- and to be clear, the code given here *does* work when properly and correctly deployed.

Comment: @codeforester how this code < <(cat "$1" -) work?. <(cat "$1" -) is a redirect to stdin? why a blank space?

Comment: `-` is interpreted as stdin by many Unix commands, including `cat`.  See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045479/whats-the-magic-of-a-dash-in-command-line-parameters

Answer (score 0):

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590548/tee-command-equivalent-for-input) seems to be helpful here:

```
{ cat $1; cat; } | while read line
   do
   echo "$line"
done
```

Or just

```
cat $1
cat
```

if all you're doing is printing the content

Comment: `cat "$1"`, you mean. Otherwise a filename with a space won't be usable. And you only need one instance of `cat`, as stdin can be referred to as `-`, as follows: `cat "$1" -`

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest `done < <(cat "$1" -)` rather than `cat "$1" - | while` to avoid [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).